# Play2.1 Snapshot on Heroku

Tags: heroku, playframework

I am running against Play! v2.1-SNAPSHOT and there was a move from play Promise to scala futures. I changed my code accordingly and run it locally - using sbt and foreman. However when I try to upload to Heroku, I get:

```
ExecutionContext is not a member of package concurrent
       [error] import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
```

I had the above error when running locally until I changed my code. I believe there is an issue with 2.1-SNAPSHOT versioning on heroku. As it looks from the [buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala/blob/master/opt/sbt-0.11.0.boot.properties), heroku loads the jar from repos that looks like http://s3pository.heroku.com/*. I guess this is for caching. If so how frequently is the cache cleared? Anyone has a solution for this?

**EDIT**

AS it seems, the ivy jars are cached as if I create a new stack within heroku using heroku create, I can deploy as normal... So my question is how do I clear the ivy cache?

Answer (score 2):

The problem as explained lies within the IVY cache between slugs. I changed the default build pack to include the following:

```
# removing SNAPSHOT.jar files to ensure we use latest
for DIR in $CACHED_DIRS ; do
  find $DIR -iname \*SNAPSHOT.jar -exec echo "deleting" {} \; -exec rm {} \;
done
```

As I did some testing and my env might be a bit outdated it might not fully work. The new buildpack is [here](https://github.com/charroch/heroku-buildpack-scala)

To add the buildpack to your env:

```
heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/charroch/heroku-buildpack-scala.git
```